# AJAX no me llama la consulta, pero sí me envía los datos

Tags: mysql, jquery, ajax, php7

Estoy realizando un buscador en tiempo real. Dicho buscador me envía perfectamente los datos y la consulta en otra página PHP me la realiza sin ningún problema, pero no me lo trae a la sección que deseo.

La página de consulta (se debería mostrar la consulta debajo del summary):

```
    <section id="muestreo">
    <?php
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
        echo "documento=" . $cc;
        echo "</script>";
        $i=1;
        $programas=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM programas");
        while ($p=mysqli_fetch_array($programas)) {
            echo "<details class='programa'>";
            echo "<summary>";
            $id_prog=$p['id_prog'];
            echo $p['nombre_prog'];
            echo "</summary>";
            echo "<form id='buscar_categorias'>";
            echo "<input type='text' name='categoria' autocomplete='off'>";
            echo "<input type='text' id='prog' name='id_prog' value='" . $id_prog ."' autocomplete='off'>";
            echo "</form>";
            echo "<section id='filtro_categoria'></section>";
            echo "</details>";
        }
    ?>
    </section>
```

Aquí el JavaScript:

```
        function consulta(){
        $.ajax({  
            type:"POST",
            url:"categorias.php",
            success:function(data) {
                $("#filtro_categoria").html(data);
            }
        });
    }
    $(document).keyup("#pedido", function(e){e.preventDefault();
        var categorias=$("#buscar_categorias").serialize();
        if (categorias!="") {
            $.ajax({  
                type:"POST",
                url:"categorias.php",
                data:categorias,
                success:function(data) {
                    alert(data);//Este alert me confirma que la consulta se realiza perfectamente.
                    consulta();
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

La página donde se realiza la consulta:

```
<?php
include('conexion.php');
if (isset($_POST['categoria']) && isset($_POST['id_prog'])) {
$id_prog=$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['id_prog']);
$c=$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['categoria']);
    $consultar_categorias=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT sub_categoria_prod FROM productos WHERE id_prog='$id_prog' AND (sub_categoria_prod LIKE '%$c%') GROUP BY sub_categoria_prod");
    $cantidad_categorias=$consultar_categorias->num_rows;
    if ($cantidad_categorias>0) {
        while ($cat=mysqli_fetch_array($consultar_categorias)) {
            echo "<details>";
            echo "<summary>";
            echo $cat['sub_categoria_prod'];
            echo "</summary>";
            echo "</details>";
        }
    }else{
        echo "No existen registros.";
    }
}
?>
```

Si ambos $_POST los dejo por fuera del isset, sí me muestra el error donde quiero, pero si todo está correcto, no me llama la consulta. ¿Alguién sabe porqué?

Comment: fijate que haces la validacion para recibir dos parametros pero en tu ajax solo envias uno "categorias" revisa eso que parametros estas enviando.. y como los revises por consola..

Comment: Sí estoy enviando dos parámetros: el id_prog y las categorias. ambos input están dentro del form y de ese form extraigo ambos datos para enviar.

Comment: ajax es un metodo asincrono por ende no espera que termine una para llamar a la otra en tal caso no se para que tienes un ajax llamando a otro?? en fin al final no le pasas data en  `consulta()` y por eso no retorna nada ya que valida `if (isset($_POST['categoria']) && isset($_POST['id_prog'])) {` y ambos van al mismo sitio :V

Comment: Voy a intentarlo.

Comment: Jajajajajaja. No puedo creer que haya funcionado. Muchas gracias. Jajajaj. Sólo por ese error.

Comment: @SantiagoCorreaAguirreSanmar de nada para ellos es la comunidad

Answer (score 0):

En el data de ajax le estas mandando únicamente la variable categorías. Intentalo de esta forma:

```
$(document).keyup("#pedido", function(e){e.preventDefault();
    if (categorias!="") {
        $.ajax({  
            type:"POST",
            url:"categorias.php",
            data:$("#buscar_categorias").serialize(),
            success:function(data) {
                alert(data);//Este alert me confirma que la consulta se realiza perfectamente.
                consulta();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

al meter el serialize directamente en el data, si que te deberían de llegar los id de los input como $_POST.

Un saludo :D

Answer (score 0):

A primeras luces el error que veo es que estás introduciendo `<form id='buscar_categorias'>` dentro del bucle. El atributo `id` debe ser único. En su lugar puedes utilizar el atributo `class`.

Una solución para agregar `id` en el bucle es agregar un número que sabemos que es único para diferenciar.

```html
<section id="muestreo">
    <?php
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
        echo "documento=" . $cc;
        echo "</script>";
        $i=1;
        $programas=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM programas");
        while ($p=mysqli_fetch_array($programas)) {
            echo "<details class='programa'>";
            echo "<summary>";
            $id_prog=$p['id_prog'];
            echo $p['nombre_prog'];
            echo "</summary>";
            echo "<form class='buscar_categorias' id='cat".$id_prog."'>";
            echo "<input type='text' name='categoria' autocomplete='off'>";
            echo "<input type='text' id='prog".$id_prog."' name='id_prog' value='" . $id_prog ."' autocomplete='off'>";
            echo "</form>";
            echo "<section id='filtro_categoria".$id_prog."'></section>";
            echo "</details>";
        }
    ?>
    </section>
```